# TypeError: Cannot read property 'toBeA' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to test my code using expect in nodejs. I required expect in code and I wanted to use a feature of expect called toBeA(). But unfortunately I 
am receiving error and unable to solve it. So,I am posting it here.

```js
const utils = require('./utils');
const expect = require('expect');
it('should add two numbers', () => {
    var result = utils.add(33,17);
    
    expect(result).toBe(50).toBeA('number');
});
```

This is my utils.js file

```js
module.exports.add = (a,b) => {
    return a+b;
};
```

When I run the code I receive this error

```
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'toBeA' of undefined
```

Comment: Might be related to this: https://github.com/mjackson/expect/issues/229

Comment: Having exactly same issue with latest 'expect' version 21.2.1. Uninstalled it and reverted installed old version which is working fine.
`> npm uninstall expect`
`> npm install expect@1.20.2 --save-dev`

Answer (score 1):

You cannot chain tests. `toBe` doesn't return anything, hence the error. You want

```
expect(result).toBe(50);
expect(result).toBeA('number');
```

(although the first one implies the other so you might as well omit it)

Comment: According to the documentation it is allowed https://github.com/mjackson/expect#chaining-assertions, maybe he is using an old version :S

Comment: expect(result).toBe(50);
expect(result).toBeA('number');

now getting new error : TypeError: expect(...).toBeA is not a function

Comment: @emed But toBe() function working fine,don't know what happen with toBeA(). Anyway,thanks.

Comment: @emed: Ah, I didn't pay attention to that. Most testing frameworks I used do no allow chaining. Or just don't know about it :-o .

Answer (score 1):

This works fine instead of toBeA()

```
expect(typeof result).toBe('number');
```

Answer (score 1):

The expect assertion library has changed ownership. It was handed over to the Jest team, who in their infinite wisdom, created a new [API](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/expect.html).

You can still install expect as before, "npm install expect --save-dev", which is currently at version 21.2.1. Most methods names will remain unchanged except for a few, including 'toExist(), toBeA()'.

Comment: what about toNotBe()

Comment: .not 
If you know how to test something, .not lets you test its opposite. For example, this code tests that the best La Croix flavor is not coconut:
test('the best flavor is not coconut', () => {
  expect(bestLaCroixFlavor()).not.toBe('coconut');
});

Answer (score 1):

when use `npm i expect --save-dev` command for install expect, automatically install last version of expect. in last version chain do not work.

for solve this problem you should use below command:

```
npm i expect@1.20.2
```

in this version you can use chain expect like `toNotBe`.